# How do I scrape a website that has alternating rows?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am working on scraping this website. http://www.vgchartz.com/games/games.php?page=1&results=500 . There are no unique tags but it looks like the background-img does a good job of identifying the rows. Below is the opening  tag for the first two rows.

```
<tr style="background-image:url(../imgs/chartBar_alt_large.gif); height:70px">
<tr style="background-image:url(../imgs/chartBar_large.gif); height:70px">
```

The backround-img alternates. Can this be used to scrape or do I need to go down the HTML tree?

There are a few  tags above these 's within the same  . The  does not have any identifiable metadata but the div which holds it does - id="generalBody".

Comment: Doesn't the first `<td>` under each `<tr>` uniquely identifies the value? Also, if you're trying to get everything on page, it doesn't matter if anything identify uniquely does it?

Comment: Which part exactly are you trying to fetch?  Can you just split the page content on `<tr style="background-image`?  Do you only want every second row?

Comment: Can't you just loop through the `<tr>`s? Why does the alternating rows matter in this situation?

Comment: I could loop trough all the tr's but there are issues. There are other <tr>'s in this table that I don't want(tables headers and nav). There are multiple tables on this page so I can't do a generalized scrape of just <tr>'s. As mentioned before the only way to distinguish this particular table might be the div ID  id="generalBody". If I start with the div and then scrape all of the <td>'s with the two background images that might be best. I had considered using only style="background-image" but I believe there are several elements on that pages that use the same base styling. Make sense?